# Rubber mulch for artillery fungus - good idea?

Tags: fungus, landscaping, mulch

We have a small bed in the front of our house as shown below.  It has had [artilery fungus](https://www.thespruce.com/artillery-fungus-identification-prevention-5185963) for the last few seasons and I want to completely be rid of it.  [image] [image]  I am considering putting in rubber mulch, as I hate having to mulch every year or two and am not very good at landscaping.  Regarding rubber mulch, I have a few questions:

1. Do the bushes shown in these pictures look like they would be ok in rubber mulch?  I've heard it's harder for plants to get nutriets, but not like we are planting flowers.  These shurbs are pretty hands off...

To remove the artillery fungus, I need to completely remove all existing mulch and dirt.  And then I've read it's important to put down landscaping fabric and then the mulch.  My next question:

2. Should we put down soil or something above/below the landscaping fabric?  For example fabrict -> dirt -> rubber mulch? This bed is very thin, basically clay and feels like I should add a bunch of dirt/soil somehow.  But it's not like it has to be as rich as garden soil.  Can I buy cheap dirt at the store or something?
3. Is there something like scotch grow pellets that I could put down each year that would seep through the mulch and give the shurbs nutrients?
4. How "deep" should the mulch be?  Can it just be a single layer (ie. 1 inch) or does it need to be 2-3 inches thick?  Does it matter?  Rubber mulch is expensive so trying to not overbuy.

Thanks

Comment: Note that rubber mulch is flammable, which may not be a great thing around a house. It also contains carcinogens. You may want to switch to rock mulch instead, which may also be cheaper. According to Penn State, rock is a viable option for preventing artillery fungus.

Comment: See https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/9467/6806

Comment: Thanks - I have read this thread before posting my question but it really don't help me with my specific concerns.  I'm not worried about it firing as I live in a relatively wet cool climate.  I'll consider rock mulch too, thanks